# Implementing a Countdown Timer in Objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nstimer

I am new to iOS programming. I am working on words matching game. In this game I need to implement time counter which shows minutes and seconds. I want when my game is started my timer to start with 3 minutes. Now I want to decrease this timer in reverse direction with seconds. my code just work for seconds..here is my code:

```
  secondsLeft--;

  int seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;

  Timerlbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",seconds];


  if (seconds==0)

{


 UIAlertView *pAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sorry!!"   
 message:@"TimeOver"        delegate:self    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"   
 otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel",nil];

 [pAlert show];

[pAlert release];

 }

 }
```

In Viewdidload i call it through timer..

```
          countDown=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self 
                 selector:@selector(TimeOver) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

pleas any one guide me how can i do it in both minutes and seconds.

Comment: Please check the following link [Count down timer](http://fromideatoapp.com/downloads/FI2ADemo-Part4.zip) It is also Pretty Handy. Regards,
Neil

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can do it like this(ARC Enabled):-

```
@interface ViewController()
{
UILabel *progress;
    NSTimer *timer;
    int currMinute;
    int currSeconds;
}
@end


@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    progress=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 15, 100, 50)];
    progress.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [progress setText:@"Time : 3:00"];
    progress.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:progress];
    currMinute=3;
    currSeconds=00;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
-(void)start
{
    timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
-(void)timerFired
{
if((currMinute>0 || currSeconds>=0) && currMinute>=0)
{
    if(currSeconds==0)
    {
        currMinute-=1;
        currSeconds=59;
    }
    else if(currSeconds>0)
    {
        currSeconds-=1;
    }
    if(currMinute>-1)
    [progress setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d%@%02d",@"Time : ",currMinute,@":",currSeconds]];
}
    else
    {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx Dear @roronoa zorro your Answer is the  best solution that i want.

Comment: Hi @roronoa-zorro , was wondering how to deal with pausing the timer?

Comment: You cannot pause or restart the Timer , you can only invalidate it.The pause & resume can be replicate by using a NSDate variable , store the current NSDate at the time you want to pause(actually invalidate) & restart the timer from the saved NSDate object

Comment: Slightly pedantic comment: `NSTimer` retains its target so this code will cause `ViewController` not to be deallocated unless its timer has reached zero. There are a bunch of workarounds mostly involving proxy objects and weak references and it doesn't even necessary really matter — quite often you have view controllers you know will never be deallocated anyway (such as the root view controller, commonly).

Answer (score 19):

I know this is old question, but I want to share my way to achieve this. We have method (timeIntervalSinceDate:) to calculate the interval and have fixed amount of seconds to count down. In my case 300 s.

**UPDATE JULY, 2015 SWIFT**

```
@IBAction func startTimer(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
    //if selected fire timer, otherwise stop
    if (sender.selected) {
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTimer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
        self.startDate = NSDate();
    } else {
        self.stopTimer();
    }

}

func stopTimer() {
    self.timer.invalidate();
}

func updateTimer() {
    // Create date from the elapsed time
    var currentDate:NSDate = NSDate();
    var timeInterval:NSTimeInterval = currentDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(self.startDate!);

    //300 seconds count down
    var timeIntervalCountDown = 300 - timeInterval;
    var timerDate:NSDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeIntervalCountDown);

    // Create a date formatter
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter();
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm:ss";
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0);

    // Format the elapsed time and set it to the label
    var timeString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(timerDate);
    self.timerLabel?.text = timeString;
}
```

[Working github swift sample project](https://github.com/gneil90/countdown-label)

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)updateTimer
{
    // Create date from the elapsed time
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate 
                                   timeIntervalSinceDate:self.startDate];
    NSLog(@"time interval %f",timeInterval);

    //300 seconds count down
    NSTimeInterval timeIntervalCountDown = 300 - timeInterval;

    NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate 
                         dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeIntervalCountDown];

    // Create a date formatter
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];


    // Format the elapsed time and set it to the label
    NSString *timeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
    self.stopWatch.text = timeString;
}

- (void)stopTimer
{
    [self.stopWatchTimer invalidate];
    self.stopWatchTimer = nil;
    [self updateTimer];

}

- (void)startTimer
{

    if (self.stopWatchTimer) {
        [self.stopWatchTimer invalidate];
        self.stopWatchTimer = nil;
    }

    self.startDate = [NSDate date];    

    // Create the stop watch timer that fires every 100 ms
    self.stopWatchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/10.0
                                           target:self
                                         selector:@selector(updateTimer)
                                         userInfo:nil
                                          repeats:YES];
}
```

**UPDATE:**

it is extremely expensive to create a NSDateFormatter each time you pass through updateTimer. Far better to create the NSDateFormatter outside the loop and reuse it. Credits: @siburb

Comment: In case anybody is going to copy/paste this verbatim (you know who you are - ), it is extremely expensive to create a `NSDateFormatter` each time you pass through `updateTimer`. Far better to create the `NSDateFormatter` outside the loop and reuse it.

Answer (score 4):

**In .h file**

```
 IBOutlet UILabel* lblTimer;
 NSTimer* gameTimer;
```

**In .m file**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self createTimer];
}

- (void)createTimer 
{       
     NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
     NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

   gameTimer = [[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.00 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] retain];
   [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:gameTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
   timeCount = 20; 
   [runLoop run];
   [pool release];
}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer 
{
    if(timeCount == 0)
    {
         [self timerExpired];
    } 
    else 
    {
         timeCount--;
        if(timeCount == 0) {
        [timer invalidate];
        [self timerExpired];
    }
 }
   lblTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d",timeCount/60, timeCount % 60];
   self.title = lblTimer.text;
}
```

Bind the above Label Outlet with Label in View.

It is working correctly with Me

Comment: NSRunLoop will hang the control if it is directed on the event invoked by action of a particular UIView'control.

Comment: [self timerExpired]; sorry what method is this calling?

Answer (score 2):

Simple and less code in Objective-C,

```
in .h file create objects for Timer and totalSeconds

 NSTimer *timer;
 int totalSeconds;

.m file
//you can call this method where you want 
[self startTimer];

-(void)startOtpTimer {
     totalSeconds = 120;//your time 
     timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self 
     selector:@selector(updateCountDownTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 }

-(void)updateCountDownTime {
    [self populateLabelwithTime:totalSeconds];
        if( totalSeconds != 0) {
            totalSeconds -= 1;
        } else {
              [timer invalidate];//stop timer
              self.timeLabel.text = @"";//after reach 0 you can set empty string
         }
}

- (void)populateLabelwithTime:(int)seconds {
    self.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", totalSeconds];
}
```

Comment: God, thanks for the internet.. I can just copy-paste and make money :)

Answer (score 1):

**OBJECTIVE-C**

**Here what we are going to achieve is a reverse countdown timer with circular progress.**

[image]

We need to follow some steps to achieve the above result in Objective-C.

A. Create XIB Files.

B. Design the layout

C. Configure the circular progress with this library. [MBCircularProgressBarView](https://github.com/MatiBot/MBCircularProgressBar)

D. Populate XIB in the UIViewController.

==============================================================

**A. Create XIB Files:**

- Go to Project Navigation and by right click, you will get the options to create a new file -> `Cocoa Touch Class` -> write `Class` Name: `ProgressDelayView`

[image]

You will get the `.h` & `.m` file named `ProgressDelayView`

Now we will create a User Interface for the class files.

[image]

This time you will get the `.xib` file named `ProgressDelayView`

Now, Assign the class name to the Interface file

[image]

**B. Design the layout**

Now design the layout according to your requirement. I have designed based on mine.

**C. Configure the circular progress with this library. [MBCircularProgressBarView](https://github.com/MatiBot/MBCircularProgressBar)**

Assign the attribute properties based on your app theme.
please check out the attributes in a screenshot.

[image]

**D. Populate XIB in the UIViewController.**

Let's move to the code part

Open your `viewcontroller.h` file

and paste this code.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface viewcontroller : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) int remainingSeconds;

@end
```

open `viewcontroller.m` and paste this

```
#import "viewcontroller.h"
#import "ProgressDelayView.h"

@interface viewcontroller(){
    ProgressDelayView *TimerTicker;
    NSTimer *timer;
}
@implementation viewcontroller
#pragma mark - Controller Lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    TimerTicker = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProgressDelayView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self populateTimeTicker];
}

-(void)populateTimeTicker {
    TimerTicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self showWithAnimation:TimerTicker];
    self.remainingSeconds = 180;
    [self startTicker];
}

-(void)startTicker {
    timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerTicker) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)timerTicker {
    self.remainingSeconds--;
    if (self.remainingSeconds == -1) {
        //dismiss alertview
        [timer invalidate];
        [TimerTicker removeFromSuperview];
        return;
    }
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.f animations:^{
        TimerTicker.progress.value = self.remainingSeconds;
    }];
}

-(void)showWithAnimation:(UIView *)customView{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.1
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
        customView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     }];
    [self.view addSubview:customView];
}
```

==============================================================

Check out these two files ProgressDelayView.h & ProgressDelayView.m

**ProgressDelayView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MBCircularProgressBarView.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface ProgressDelayView : UIView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MBCircularProgressBarView *progress;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**ProgressDelayView.m**

```
#import "ProgressDelayView.h"

@implementation ProgressDelayView

@end
```

HURRAY hit the `⌘R`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSTimer` to achieve this.

Comment: Check out this tutorial, it will help you in achieve what you want - http://pravinmagdum.wordpress.com/tag/nstimer-tutorial/

Comment: Checkout this, might be this is causing issue to you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340930/stray-342-in-c-program

Comment: Thanx now its Work fine Dear @rishi a lot a thanx for helping me.now i satified to accept Your are Answer thanx.

Comment: I don't understand your answer and those links. Is it relevant to the question?