# Countdown from current time, schedule

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nstimer

I want to have a countdown from the current time to a specific schedule like this:
8:48, 9:29, 11:56, 12:36, 13:18, and ect. and display that value in a label.

For example. Now we have 11:00 o'clock. And UILabel tell us 56 minutes remaining. And after 11:56 it tell us 40 minutes remaining (from current 11:56 to 12:36).

I don't ask you code directly, just help to find right way to search.
Thanks.

Comment: it would be great if you said I tried this code but didn't succeeded, instead of demanding for code directly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

some links by searching google
[Implementing a Countdown Timer in Objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663184/implementing-a-countdown-timer-in-objective-c)
http://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/ios-timer-countdown-implementation-tutorial-including-source-code/

and implementation
https://github.com/jonhernandez/iOS-Timer-Countdown

I havent looked at code quality, but it should get you started