# What is the proper way of declaring a floating point number in exponential form as a macro in C/C++?

Tags: c++, macros

I was trying to create a really simple program to calculate the gravitational force between two objects in C++. So I wanted to declare a macro for G whose value is equal to 6.754*10^-11 and I used this:

```
#define G 6.754e-11.0;
```

But it generated a lot of stray errors as shown below:

```
cd '~/Desktop/CS/C++/Other PSETS'
g++ gravity.cpp -o gravity
```

Output:

```
gravity.cpp:5:28: error: stray ‘\342’ in program
 #define G (6.754)*pow(10.0,��11.0);
                            ^
gravity.cpp:10:52: note: in expansion of macro ‘G’
     float gforce(float m1,float m2,float r){return G*m1*m2/(r*r);}
                                                    ^
gravity.cpp:5:29: error: stray ‘\210’ in program
 #define G (6.754)*pow(10.0,��11.0);
                             ^
gravity.cpp:10:52: note: in expansion of macro ‘G’
     float gforce(float m1,float m2,float r){return G*m1*m2/(r*r);}
                                                    ^
gravity.cpp:5:30: error: stray ‘\222’ in program
 #define G (6.754)*pow(10.0,�11.0);
                              ^
gravity.cpp:10:52: note: in expansion of macro ‘G’
     float gforce(float m1,float m2,float r){return G*m1*m2/(r*r);}
```

So, I decided to use the math library function `cmath` for using `pow()`, but still it wasn't of any use. What can I do to create such a macro?

*Note*: I am Using G++ on Ubuntu as shown below:

```
g++ --version
```

Output:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3) 7.2.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: remove the `;` at the end of the `#define...` line

Comment: Also don't use macros.

Comment: I highly advise not to use 1-letter names such as `G`.

Comment: *`stray ‘\342’ in program`* did you do copy&paste from a website? Sometimes characters that look the same but are different are used on websites, mostly `”` is used instead of `"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stray '\342' in C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340930/stray-342-in-c-program)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It's a physical constant and it's `G`, so in this case it is a very good idea to do that.

Comment: @nwp, what? why not?

Comment: Apart from the `;` that is not the answer. `6.754e-11` works fine, but `6.754e-11.0` does not, trying to find why.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, I don't think that you can express numeric literals with a floating point exponent.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi thanks, was just arriving at that conclusion.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Because they make the program harder to read, write and optimize. Use a `constexpr double` instead.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi because if macros are use improperly, you can have very well hidden bugs. Consider `#define abs(x) ((x) > 0 ? (x) : (-x))`. This looks harmless, but `int i = -3; abs(--x);` would lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Pablo Following that reasoning then if knifes are used improperly, you can have murdering and injuries.

Comment: "The stray `\342`" is a red herring. That line copy/pasted into a program compiles when the `.0;` is removed. Nothing to do with any minus sign encoding.

Comment: @nwp please note that this is c++ specific. Macros are not, and you can suggest that being more specific like "*in c++ it's not recommended to use macros*". Macros as any language feature when used correctly can be very useful, writing bad macros like the example by @[Pablo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308886/what-is-the-proper-way-of-declaring-a-floating-point-number-in-exponential-form#comment83603616_48308886) is possible too, but that's no reason to simple BAN macros.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi if you **really** know how to use macros and understand the ups and downs of using them, then sure, use them. And yes, if you use knifes improperly, you **can** have murdering and injuries. So if you don't know how to use a knife properly, don't use it.

Comment: @WeatherVane The U+2212, the `.0` in the exponent, and the semicolon are _all_ problems, of equal significance to the compiler (that is, they all provoke syntax errors).

Comment: @zwol I see now the C++ tag, I am using a C compiler.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I'm not from banning macros, I only gave you an example of a common pitfall using macros and why you should avoid them, unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: @WeatherVane C and C++ should both reject `#define G 6.754e−11` (provided that the macro is actually expanded as part of an arithmetic expression). I think it's more likely that somewhere along the copy-and-paste chain from OP's code to your test program the Unicode character got degraded to ASCII.

Comment: @zwol I guess so (about the stray) - as OP's compiler says.

Comment: This is a ***very*** common error when copying code from web pages, [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) documents, through chat (e.g. [Skype Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#Skype_chat) or [Facebook Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Messenger)), etc. The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*.

Comment: Prefer proper (`const`) variables over macros when possible.

Comment: There are really two questions here: 1) The stray errors 2) The macro question. They ought to be two separate questions (posts).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message

```
stray ‘\342’ in program
```

means your program contains a character which is not allowed by the syntax of C++ (technically, it is outside the "basic source character set").  The three-digit number is the octal encoding of the numeric value of the problem *byte*.  You got three of these in a row, so the offending byte sequence is `0342 0210 0222`, which is the UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character U+2212 MINUS SIGN.

That's right. You're not allowed to use minus signs in C++.  You must use U+002D HYPHEN-MINUSes instead.

To fix that part of the problem, in your editor go to the line

```
#define G 6.754e-11.0;
```

backspace over the minus sign and retype it.  This probably happened because you copied and pasted the number from a web page or PDF that uses fancy (by which I mean "not just plain ASCII") typography.

You will still need to fix a couple other problems.  That semicolon shouldn't be there at all, because `#define`s end at the end of the line.  And the exponent of a floating-point literal in C++ must be an integer.  So what you really should have is

```
#define G 6.754e-11
```

It is also arguably better to use a `const` variable for this, as you do not *need* a macro:

```
const double G = 6.754e-11;
```

(note that the semicolon has now returned) ... but I am old-school enough to not object to the use of macros for numeric constants.

There is absolutely no reason to use `pow` here.

Comment: A more direct way is searching in a modern text editor or IDE using the regular expression `\x{2212}` (or `\x{2212}`, for example, in [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)). This also works where the visuals are not enough, e.g. U+00A0 ([NO-BREAK SPACE](https://www.charset.org/utf-8)) and U+200B ([ZERO WIDTH SPACE](https://www.charset.org/utf-8/9)).